# What step am I missing in creating a cron job?

Tags: cron

I can't seem to run cron jobs and I can't figure out why. I'm new to this so I might be making an amateur mistake.

First, I create a script and call it 'test.sh', putting it in the /usr/local/bin folder. The script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This test works!"
```

Next, I create a file called 'randomtest' in the /etc/cron.d folder. The file contains:

```
00 09 * * * root /usr/local/bin/test.sh >> /var/log/test.log
```

I expect the cron job to run at 9:00 AM every day, but for some reason, it doesn't. I also don't get a log file as expected. I checked the permissions on the test.sh file and it's currently set to 755, which should work.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Am I missing a crucial element? Do I need to add my 'randomtest' file to the crontab or something?

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? You can check [Cron How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#line-141). Check that the cron daemon is running with `ps -ef | grep cron`.

Comment: I'm running CentOS 4.4, linux kernel version 2.6.18-308.el5. Cron daemon is indeed running.

Comment: What if you use `crontab -e` and normal crontab?

Comment: I did `crontab -e` which opened an empty file, to which I inserted `00 09 * * * root /usr/local/bin/test.sh >> /var/log/test.log`. Nothing happened :(.

Comment: What if you remove the `root` part and add the binary --> `00 09 * * * /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/test.sh >> /var/log/test.log`

Comment: ^ That did not work. However, I reloaded my cron daemon, and it started working. After that, I deleted my script, my 'randomtest' file in cron.d, removed the user crontab entry and started again with a clean slate. When I created 'randomtest' in cron.d and 'test.sh' this time, it worked just fine (WITHOUT reloading the cron daemon). It's now working as it is supposed to, and I don't get what was wrong in the first place and why I had to reload my cron daemon the first time (I made sure it was already running).

Comment: Don't mess around with the `/etc/cron.d` directory. Just use the `crontab` command. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload the cron daemon by using `/etc/init.d/crond reload`.

(Even if it's already running!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're messing around with the `/etc/cron.d` directory rather than using the `crontab` command.

Unless you definitely need a cron job to run as `root`, just add it to your own crontab using the `crontab` command. You can use `crontab -e` to edit it, but it's better to keep your own copy of your crontab (ideally under version control) and use the `crontab filename` version of the command to install it. This ensure that the cron daemon will be aware of the update, and that any syntax errors will be caught. It also means you don't need to run any commands as `root`; avoiding `root` commands *unless they're actually necessary* is always a good idea.

Note that system crontabs (those in `/etc/crontab` and under the `/etc/cron.d` directory -- though those locations are implementation details that you ideally shouldn't have to worry about) have a different syntax than user crontabs; each line has an extra field that specifies the account under which the commans is to be run.

If you need a command to run as root, you can either update a system crontab file (*carefully!*), or you can set up a user crontab for the `root` user, using the normal `crontab` command as you would for any user account.